# Graphic manga about teenagers trained to fight in a war, using powers rather than guns

Tags: story-identification, manga

Basically, the story distinctly starts with a class of high school-age students getting deployed into a war taking place in a city against these unknown terrorists. The horrors of war are very quickly shown when multiple students are gunned down, with heads and limbs being torn off their bodies gruesomely.

The premise of the story, from what I remember, is that Japan takes kids, trains them in an academy, and sees them fight. One thing: the kids have powers, and they cannot use guns. Apparently this is because Japan isn’t allowed to use guns in wars or something; I can’t remember the plot very well. So basically, you see these kids trying their best to fight a war without using guns, and it results in a lot of death and bloodshed.

A few more scenes I remember: the kids regroup on a rooftop and the most popular kid gets his brains blown out by a sniper. An asshole prototype jock gets his nuts completely blown off, and that’s one of the things I remember well. Also one of the main character’s right-hand men is this dude who’s really apathetic and sadistic, with a radio/communication type ability. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds vaguely reminiscent of _Battle Royale_, but if your description is accurate, it's definitely not that. When did you read this incidentally, and do you have any idea when it was first published?

Comment: No it’s not that. I read it about a year and a half ago I think. I can’t remember when It was published but I think it had around 20-30 chapters.

Comment: @Balls You seem to have created two separate accounts here, since you're replying to the above comment with a different account from the one you used to ask the question. If you [merge and register](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts, then you can respond more easily to comments/answers on your question.

Comment: @Balls - If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, please [upvote](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that answer and mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) so we know to keep looking. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is *[Kimi Shi ni Tamau Koto Nakare / Thou Shalt Not Die](https://myanimelist.net/manga/81683/Kimi_Shi_ni_Tamau_Koto_Nakare)*, which began its run in 2014.

[image]

> In the future, supernatural powers not only exist but have become science fact. The "Special Abilities Private High School" is established in order to utilize students' powers for the military. Students are roped onto the battlefield without knowing the meaning of the fight, whether it will save their lives... or spell their demise.

It has everything you mentioned: the students who fight with powers and blades only (no guns), the military academy, Japan being prohibited from entering into acts of war, the sniper, a boy getting his brains blown out, another boy getting shot in the nether regions, etc.

This was apparently adapted into [a stage play](https://firesanctuary.com/tsnd-zerokai/) as well. As a big fan of *Battle Royale*, I'd love to see a movie version.

[image]